# How to get value of response headers in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const URL = 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816222/? 
ref_ = fn_al_tt_2 ';

(async() => {

    const response = await request({
      uri: URL,
      headers: {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/0.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'

      },

    });
```

I need help from this code. How can I get the response header values in console of visual studio code for the following site.

Comment: Show us what you have tried?

Comment: Please add all code to the question itself, not to the comment section

Comment: if my answer was useful, please mark as correct.

Comment: accept the answer if found the correct solution.

Comment: @Ariz that's what I meant actually...I miss the word at the time :D

Comment: @ElmerDantas still no response. :D

Comment: @Ariz the first upvote might have come from him....anyway, just wondering if he manage to solve.

Comment: @ElmerDantas he did have replied to my solution that it worked, so I ASSUME it did.

Answer (score 1):

Just handle the Promise from `request` library

```
  request({
    uri: 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816222/?',
    headers: /*your headers*/ 
    })
    .then(function(response){
       console.log(response.headers)
    })
```

Comment: That's the same of async/await

Comment: @CristianTraìna I just look at his comment where it's written `require('request-promise')` and assume that async/await is not supported, that's why I've posted the Promise approach.

Comment: @ElmerDantas why async await is not supported with request-promise? it returns a promise only.

Comment: @Ariz I've said "I assume" that is not supported. Just a guess. The only reason for posting a Promise approach.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the response headers in response.headers

Comment: But It says undefined?

Comment: console.log(response.headers);
Or
console.log(response.headers['user-agent']);
tried both but nothing works

Comment: I think the issue is that request module doesn't return a promise.It accepts a callback.So you can't use async await syntax in this case

Comment: so what to do? Is there any method?

Answer (score 0):

Print like this

```
console.log(response.headers)
```

Comment: const request = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const URL = 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816222/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2';

(async () => {

    const response = await request({
        uri:URL,
       headers:{
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/0.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'

       },
     
    });

   console.log(response.headers);
        
})()

Answer (score 0):

This code prints headers:

```
const URL = 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816222/?ref_ = fn_al_tt_2';
const request = require('request');

(async () => {

  const response = await request({
    uri: URL,
    headers: {
      'Connection': 'keep-alive',
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/0.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'

    },

  });
  console.log(response.headers);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are just fetching the body of response from request npm.

add resolveWithFullResponse: true in request options.

```js
const URL = 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816222/? 
ref_ = fn_al_tt_2 ';

(async() => {

    const response = await request({
      uri: URL,
      headers: {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/0.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'

      },
 resolveWithFullResponse: true
    });
```

if you need to only headers

```js
const URL = 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816222/? 
ref_ = fn_al_tt_2 ';

(async() => {

    const {headers} = await request({
      uri: URL,
      headers: {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/0.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'

      },
 resolveWithFullResponse: true
    });
    
    console.log(headers)
```

Comment: thanks brother it worked now reverse it how can we get the request headers  instead of response and how can we get only one specific header value and store it in variable?

Comment: now response.header is just a native object so you simply can do response.header['content-type'] etc, here you will get the value of content-type header.
updated answer if you need only header.